# Provision Failed while creating a web site in Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I've created a free-trial account on windowsazure.com and I've been trying to deploy a web site (specifically wordpress-type) without any luck so far.I've even tried with the "quick create"-type same results.

The only thing that maybe is of interest, is the e-mail address used for login in Windows Account (Live ID whatever) that even though is used as the ID for all MS services as an e-mail is not because it is very old and deactivated. In the profile of my windows azure account it is the active one, as should. At at the bottom of the error message it specifies my OLD email used for the login ID. I don't know if it has anything to do, I'm just mentioning it.

How can this be solved?

> Provision failed.
>
> Try again. Contact support if the problem persists.
>
> Browser: 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
>   .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; Media Center
>   PC 6.0; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7; 69690224903; Library1.08088)
>
> User language: en-gb
>
> Portal Version: 6.0.6002.18488 (rd_auxportal_stable.120913-1406)
>
> Subscriptions: fe59543f-a824-44e7-8565-3e3d4e4569ec
>
> User email address: *"my OLD email address here, which is the Live
>   ID"*

Comment: I've reported this to the team that can resolve it for you. I'm sorry for the trouble and it should be corrected soon. [UPDATE]
This should be fixed now. Jim Cheshire
Windows Azure Web Sites
Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

First of all above subscription is a valid and active subscription along with Windows Azure Websites are also enabled. I could also verify that there is only one email account associated with above subscription. Your email (orgID - *.gr) which is associated with this account has both service level and administration level capability.

What you try is to login into old portal and add another Live ID (hotmail, live or Outlook.com) as co-admin and then use that Email ID to log into the portal again and then create the website. This should solve above problem.

If you still have problem, your best option is to contact Windows Azure Websites team directly from dedicated forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads).

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out and come back.

Comment: Didn't work either. I did add a newly created account under outlook dot com but the result is the same. Guess have to take it to the Azure team as you suggest.